# Should I host my site on my own hardware for streaming media site?

Tags: web-hosting, video-streaming

We are developing a new movie review site, more or less similar to RottenTomatoes. Now since there will be a lot of streaming of movie trailers and we are expecting medium traffic, do you think 3rd party web hosting will cost a lot? Should we rather go for our own hardware server software?
We expect around 10GB of streaming to happen per month from 2 - 6 months of web site launch. Less before and more after that period.
What do you suggest?

Thanks 
Sridhar Reddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with some sort of cloud based solution to get a sense of what you traffic is going to look like.  Once you've got some data on hand you can figure out how much hardware you would have to purchase and what the costs over time of a self hosted solution would look like compared to the cloud solution.

If you host your own solution, keep in mind that in addition to the hardware costs, you will also have the costs for power, bandwidth, and hardware/infrastructure maintenance.  You'll need to include all of these when comparing the relative benefit of self hosting with a hosted/cloud solution.

Comment: Any reason why I should go for cloud solution? I cant bear dedicated hosting as of now, so, how is it better over shared hosting?

Comment: First of all you can scale up faster with cloud if you run into the need.

Comment: What sysadmin1138 said.  Since at least for some value of the word "cloud" it implies an api-backed, arbitrary number of instances/pay per usage model, it's easier to spin up a bunch of new machines on demand.